# With chrome.storage, how to save a string into local storage and then test for existence?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am writing a chrome extension where I want to save a string (an URL) into local stage and later test for existence.

For example:

```
function getURL(e) {
  let domain = e.url;

  //if domain does not exist in local storage, save domain into local storage
}
```

I looked the tutorial on both `chrome.storage.local.get()` and `set()`, but I still can not figure an easy way to do this.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is, really. Add more details. For example why do you need to check the existence? You can just save the domain directly: chrome.storage.local.set({[domain]: true}). But in case you want to keep it in a single key as an array it'll be different of course.

Comment: @woxxom: basically I want to do something if a domain has not been seen before. I would prefer to save each domain in a separate key, since later on I may want to associate each domain with more properties. From the tutorial and examples I can't figure out how to use variable as a key, and then set and get from local storage.

Comment: Ah. You need to do the check inside the callback e.g. chrome.storage.local.get(domain, r => { if (!r[domain]) { chrome.storage.local.set({[domain]: {foo: 'bar'}})  } });

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save it in an array and then test it.

```js
function getURL(e) {
  let domain = e.url;

  //if domain does not exist in local storage, save domain into local storage

  // get the saved `urls`
  chrome.storage.local.get("urls", i => {
    // urls might not saved before 
    let urls = i.urls || []
    // test if exists
    if (!urls.includes(domain)) {
      urls.push(domain)
      //save it into store
      chrome.storage.local.set({urls})
    }
  })
}
```